# Basic security for entries using checkboxes

Tags: security, pixelandtonic

I'm trying to put in place a basic security system for entries and this is what I've put in a checkbox field. Is it possible to put these global variable in the conditional or do I need to find a better solution?

```
{if ({document_security:selected option=logged_in_group_id})}
    ... content ..
{/if}
```

Comment: Can you please explain more about what you are trying to achieve: What kind of security system? Which add-ons are you using? What are your channels and fields called? What is that code snippet supposed to achieve? Why did you tag this `pixelandtonic`?

Answer (score 0):

user809 - I think you're trying to restrict who can view entries on the front-end.  Have you tried something like [Entry Access](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/entry-access)?